# How to list special HTML tags?

Tags: html, listings

I'm looking to customise our eBay listings HTML. What I'd like to do is link to some of our own eBay categories, eBay custom pages, and our eBay store front.

Obviously I can just create a standard HTML anchor, but I need to drop in some eBay custom tags if they have them. I need:

- Our shop URL
- Our category URL
- Our custom pages URL

We have over 8,000 listings, and if we change the name of our store, or the name of a category (or if eBay change their URL structure), I don't want to have to update all 8,000 again because my HTML links are suddenly wrong. I need to do something like:

```
<a href="{CategoryURL ID=123}">Category</a>
```

and:

```
<a href="{StoreURL}">Store Home</a>
```

This way, if a name changes the URL's will too.

I have found these pages:

- http://pages.ebay.com.sg/help/account/html-tags.html
- http://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/specialtysites/stores-specific-tags.html

However, they don't include any URLs.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the HTML Builder:
[image]